# How to change a gtk image button in C

Tags: c, linux, gtk3, glade

I've tried many things but I can't change the image in a button. In my case, I would like to change the image of the button that allows to put my application in full screen and vice versa.
I tried to use several functions in the documentation as well as on the forums but nothing seems to work. Do you have any solutions to offer me?
Thank you for your help :)

Below is the last thing I tried before relying on you:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <err.h>

typedef struct Application Application;
struct Application
{
    //Builder
    GtkBuilder      *builder;

    //Windows
    GtkWidget       *splashscreen;
    GtkWidget       *window_main;

    //Buttons
    GtkWidget       *button_close;
    GtkWidget       *button_fullscreen;

    //Image
    GtkWidget        *img_fullscreen;
    GtkWidget        *img_leave_fullscreen;

    //Label
    GtkLabel        *progresslabel;

    //ProgressBar
    GtkProgressBar  *progressbar;

    //Error
    GError          *error;

    //Data
    int             is_fullscreen;
};

//Doesn't work fine :( Impossible to change picture in the button
void change_fullscreen_mode(gpointer app_data){

    Application *app = app_data;

    /* Check if picture is fullscreen or not */
    if(app->is_fullscreen == 1)
    {
        // try to assign appropriate picture to the button
        gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(app->button_fullscreen),
                            app->img_leave_fullscreen);
        //unfullscreen the window of course
        gtk_window_unfullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(app->window_main));
        //set the variable that stands for this state
        app->is_fullscreen = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // try to assign appropriate picture to the button
        gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(app->button_fullscreen),
                            app->img_fullscreen);
        //fullscreen the window of course
        gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(app->window_main));
        //set the variable that stands for this state
        app->is_fullscreen = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Init gtk
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    Application app;
    app.error = NULL;
    app.is_fullscreen = 1;

    //Create builder
    app.builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( app.builder, "app.glade", &(app.error)))
    {
        g_warning( "%s", app.error->message );
        g_free( app.error );
        return(1);
    }

    //Get back gtk object
    app.splashscreen = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(app.builder,
                   "splashscreen"));
    app.progresslabel = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(app.builder,
                   "progresslabel"));
    app.progressbar = GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(gtk_builder_get_object(app.builder,
                   "progressbar"));
    app.window_main = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(app.builder,
                   "window_main"));
    app.button_close = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(app.builder,
                   "button_close"));
    app.button_fullscreen = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(app.builder,
                   "button_fullscreen"));

    //assign a picture for each mode
    app.img_leave_fullscreen =
        gtk_image_new_from_file("icons/tools/gtk-leave-fullscreen18x18.png");

    app.img_fullscreen =
        gtk_image_new_from_file("icons/tools/gtk-fullscreen18x18.png");

    //fill the container with one picture (works find)
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(app.button_fullscreen),
                      app.img_leave_fullscreen);

    ...

    //Connect signals
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(app.builder, NULL); //builder

    g_signal_connect(app.window_main, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),
                    NULL);
    g_signal_connect(app.button_close, "clicked",
                    G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    //quit splashscreen
    g_signal_connect (app.splashscreen, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit),
                    NULL);

    //change fullscreen mode with the corresponding button
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(app.button_fullscreen), "clicked",
        G_CALLBACK(change_fullscreen_mode), &app);

    g_object_unref(app.builder);

    gtk_widget_hide(app.window_main);
    gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(app.splashscreen));
    gtk_widget_show(app.splashscreen);
    eventstartCommand = g_timeout_add(5, on_start_commands, &app);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You first add an image via `gtk_container_add` and then try to change it via `gtk_button_set_image`. Did you try to use `gtk_button_set_image` for the initial image as well?

Comment: Any feedback yet?

Comment: Hi, excuse me for not coming back. It's kind of my fault. I've had time to run several more tests but nothing works. For starters, I tested what you told me. I thought I had already tested that, but last I heard it sent me back a segfault. Unfortunately, I don't have the exact error to show it to you anymore but it inspired new keywords for my research and I came across this site: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-properly-add-images-to-buttons/1185/2

Comment: So I continued my research following this discovery and I think I have solved the bottom of the problem. Except that this time I have a rather strange segfault. It seems to come from the line: `if(app->is_fullscreen == 1)`
By displaying app->is_fullscreen I realized that it was initialized to a random value as if it was not initialized. However, I was sure it was working at the very beginning before I started changing the image. I will continue my tests but I feel like I really don't master what I'm doing.

Comment: In the end I solved all my problems which were no longer related to the change of image as I suspected. The site I gave provided the solution that worked for me :) Or else, the problem I had just above was related to the number of arguments in the call of my change_fullscreen_mode function. I added a GtkButton in front of the gpointer. I have a warning for unused variable but it works!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately you didn't get the segfault all the time. With that information it would have been easier to spot the error. In the end you learned that you always must stick to the signature of the signal handler function as given in the [reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked). In addition you might take a closer look at [g_signal_connect_swapped()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-swapped)